# Dynamically-created Twilio Enqueue waitUrl results in 500 server error

Tags: php, laravel, rest, twilio

I have a function in my Laravel application that generates TwiML for a holding queue. It seems that when I try to dynamically generate the value for the waitUrl attribute, I end up getting a 500 server error during runtime. Routes are properly established and I'm able to view the correct XML at the waitURL in the browser. However, the error persists.

If I create a static XML file with the same exact content, or use a TwiML Bin, it works like a charm.

Here are the relevant functions:

```
public function wait() {
  return $this->generateWaitTwiml();
}

public function onHold($agentId) {
  return $this->generateHoldQueueTwiml($agentId, '/phone/wait');
}

private function generateHoldQueueTwiml($agentId, $waitUrl = null) {
  $queue = $agentId . '_hold';
  if ($waitUrl === null){
    $waitUrl = 'path_to_static.xml';
  }
  $queue = $agentId . '_hold';
  $response = new Twiml();
  $response->enqueue(
    $queue,
    ['waitUrl' => $waitUrl]
  );
  return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}

private function generateWaitTwiml() {
  $response = new Twiml();
  $response
    ->play('http://path_to_my.mp3');

  return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the 500 is because there is an error being thrown at some point. Can you include a stack trace for the error at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by excluding the URIs from the CSRF verification (in VerifyCsrfToken.php):

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware {
    protected $except = [
        'uri/',
        'uri2/*',
    ];
}
```